# Problema com Requisição via GET

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, pdo

Estou usando com sucesso o script abaixo para abrir na DIV Visual, os produtos referentes a marca selecionada:

Link das Marcas:

`<a class="marca" style="cursor:pointer;" id="'.$res['codigo'].'">'.$res['nome_marca'].'</a>`

Script para as Marcas:

```
<script language="javascript">
////// Visualiza o produto da Marca selecionada //////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.marca').click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({url:"prod_index_marca.php?codmarca="+cod,success:function(data){
            $('#visual').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Na sequencia, gostaria de abrir os detalhes de cada produto da Marca selecionada de dentro da DIV Visual, para ela mesmo.

Usei o mesmo método para abrir das Marcas, ficando assim:

Link para os Detalhes dos produtos:

```
<a class="detalhe_5" style="cursor:pointer;" id="<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>">
    <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/<?php echo $res['img01']; ?>" />
</a>
```

Script para os Detalhes:

```
<script language="javascript">
////// Para visualizar o item selecionado //////
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".detalhe_5").click(function(){
        var cod = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo="+cod,success:function(data){
            $("#visual").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Mas não estou obtendo resposta, quando clico no link, a página fica estática, ou seja nada acontece.

Posso contar com os amigos para solucionar esse problema?

Não estou conseguindo descobrir o porque não funciona.

Comment: No console apresenta algum erro?

Comment: se você acessar a url diretamente no navegador obtém alguma resposta?

Comment: Olá Lucas Brogni, sim acessei a URL e me retornou a seguinte mensagem: "Undefined index: codigo in C:\wamp\www\Commerce\prod_detalhes_5.php on line 11" .

Comment: E na página "prod_detalhes_5.php" está assim:

Comment: `<?php
        $codigo = $_GET['codigo'];
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo = $codigo") or die(mysql_error());
        $sql->execute();
        foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){
    ?>`